# MySQL - on delete cascade

Tags: mysql, database

We have several tables with foreign keys. I've checked their CREATE statements, and there was no 'ON DELETE CASCADE' option enabled anywhere.

I would like to find out whether it is possible to delete Parent, and all the related rows in Child with providing some command during the DELETION of row in the Parent.

Possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no ON DELETE CASCADE on a table, you could try implementing it with a AFTER DELETE trigger.

Otherwise, ON DELETE CASCADE can be defined easily. However, please be careful, especially if a child table has multiple constraints.

Answer (score 0):

[It is a valid option](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table.html), The code below works as expected.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TestFoo;
CREATE TABLE TestFoo
(
    Foo INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY(Foo)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS TestBar;
CREATE TABLE TestBar
(
    Bar INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    Foo INT,
    PRIMARY KEY(Bar),
    FOREIGN KEY bar_foo (Foo)
      REFERENCES TestFoo (Foo)
      ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;

INSERT TestFoo VALUES (NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL);
INSERT TestBar(Foo) VALUES (1),(2),(3),(4);
SELECT * FROM TestBar;
DELETE FROM TestFoo WHERE Foo = 2 OR Foo = 3;
SELECT * FROM TestBar;
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Sorry, if it was not clear. Actually, this 'ON DELETE CASCADE' was not used during the creation of tables. Is there any chance for me to utilize cascade option in some way, by adding in the deletion query?

Comment: @firefox Can you alter the constraint? How about @Rolando's answer with a trigger, is that good for you?

Comment: Yeah, I get it. Although I could not change the constraints, but understood how it can be done. Thanks guys.